# Android Virtual Device & Intel HAXM

Tags: android, haxm

I've just set up a new PC with Android Studio, and can't launch any Virtual Devices. When I start a device I get the message-

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'Nexus_5_API_21_x86'
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

When I run the HAXM installer, it says

```
This computer meets the requirements for haxm but intel virtualization is not turned on
```

But in BIOS its definately ticked as being ON.

Any ideas why I can't get it working ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so some antivirus prevent HAXM running, and make sure you don't have Windows Hypervisor running. (Under programs list, windows, under H).

Comment: Looks like Avast! AntiVirus was the problem. It uses Virtualisation, I disabled the option but HAXM didnt install. I uninstalled Avast! & then HAXM installed properly ! Thank you codecats.

Answer (score 0):

It could be you need to set your NX (XD) bit to on. As admin run from command line: 
bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn
Otherwise what is your CPU?

Answer (score 0):

```
Windows 8. Android Studio.
Make sure if virtualization is enable : go through those steps provided below.
```

- Goto setting -> change pc settings-> general->then see on right side
  by scrolling the frame down-> you will see under advance start up
  restart now button press it->then choose an option window will
  open->choose troubleshoot->under troubleshoot choose Advance
  option->then under Advance options choose UEFI Firmware option->then
  press restart->press f10 for BIOS->see the menubar where you will
  find system configuration menu inside it you will see the
  virtualization Technology "enable" it ->now go for exit saving
  changes in exit on menu bar..

  C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm-android.exe

  (in username : please enter valid user name)

  install it and restart your Android Studio.

  if you make few changes on above process it is same for win 7 and also same for eclipse

  hope it helps have fun!!